# Multiple grouped counts against categories and subcategories

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database, mysql-5.7

I'm trying to query analytical data from a MySQL 5.7 database for displaying in the frontend. This data is in a many to many structure, and I want to aggregate two columns, one based on the information in the previous column, grouped and counted by date.

The intention is to get data in the following format (see the example data):

```
entry_date | cat_name | subcat_name | subcat_count | total_count
-----------|----------|-------------|--------------|------
2020-07-28 | #TestOne | Alpha       | 1            | 2
2020-07-28 | #TestOne | Delta       | 1            | 2
2020-07-27 | #TestTwo | Bravo       | 1            | 2
2020-07-27 | #TestTwo | Charlie     | 1            | 2
2020-07-26 | #TestOne | Charlie     | 1            | 2
2020-07-26 | #TestOne | Bravo       | 1            | 2
2020-07-25 | #TestTwo | Delta       | 1            | 2
2020-07-25 | #TestTwo | Alpha       | 1            | 2
```

In the above data, `value` is the quantity of a given type against a given scenario on a given date, and `total` is the quantity of all types against a scenario on a given day. So if there were a hundred posts with type `Alpha` on one day, that value would be `100` and the total would be `100`. If there were another hundred posts with type `Delta`, the total would become `200`.

I got as far as this before I realised I was lost:

```
SELECT
    ct.entry_id,
    DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(ct.entry_date)) AS entry_date,
    cg.group_name,
    c.cat_name
FROM
    category_posts cp
    LEFT JOIN channel_titles ct ON ct.entry_id = cp.entry_id
    LEFT JOIN categories c ON c.cat_id = cp.cat_id
    LEFT JOIN category_groups cg ON cg.group_id = c.group_id
WHERE
    cg.group_name = 'Group A'
    OR cg.group_name = 'Group B'
GROUP BY
    entry_date,
    group_name,
    cat_name
ORDER BY
    entry_id,
    FIELD(group_name, 'Group A', 'Group B')
```

This returned data in an unreliable and less useful format, but was okay – if you could be absolutely certain of the presence of records in Group A, which I couldn't be.

```
entry_id | entry_date | group_name | cat_name
---------|------------|------------|---------
1        | 2020-07-28 | Group A    | #TestOne
1        | 2020-07-28 | Group B    | Alpha
1        | 2020-07-28 | Group B    | Delta
2        | 2020-07-27 | Group A    | #TestTwo
2        | 2020-07-27 | Group B    | Bravo
2        | 2020-07-27 | Group B    | Charlie
3        | 2020-07-26 | Group A    | #TestOne
3        | 2020-07-26 | Group B    | Charlie
3        | 2020-07-26 | Group B    | Bravo
4        | 2020-07-25 | Group A    | #TestTwo
4        | 2020-07-25 | Group B    | Delta
4        | 2020-07-25 | Group B    | Alpha
```

#### Entity Relationship Diagram

[image: Entity Relationship Diagram]

#### Example Data

**category_groups**

```
group_id | group_name
---------|------------------------------
1        | Group A
2        | Group B
```

**categories**

```
cat_id | group_id | cat_name
-------|----------|-------------------
1      | 1        | #TestOne
2      | 1        | #TestTwo
3      | 2        | Alpha
4      | 2        | Bravo
5      | 2        | Charlie
6      | 2        | Delta
```

**category_posts**

```
cat_id | entry_id
-------|---------
1      | 1
2      | 2
1      | 3
2      | 4
3      | 1
4      | 2
5      | 3
6      | 4
6      | 1
5      | 2
4      | 3
3      | 4
```

**channel_titles**

```
entry_id | entry_date
---------|-----------
1        | 1595940540 (07/28/2020)
2        | 1595882160 (07/27/2020)
3        | 1595721600 (07/26/2020)
4        | 1595635200 (07/25/2020)
```

Answer (score 0):

The original version of the question did not specify MySQL 5.7.  This answer requires MySQL 8.0.

But I think this is just an aggregation query with a window function:

```
SELECT ct.entry_id,
       DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(ct.entry_date)) AS entry_date,
       cg.group_name,
       COUNT(*) as value,
       SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY entry_id,  DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(ct.entry_date)) as total
FROM category_posts cp JOIN
     channel_titles ct
     ON ct.entry_id = cp.entry_id JOIN
     categories c
     ON c.cat_id = cp.cat_id JOIN
     category_groups cg
     ON cg.group_id = c.group_id
WHERE cg.group_name IN ( 'Group A', 'Group B' )
GROUP BY entry_date, group_name;
```

I removed the `LEFT JOIN`s because your data all seems to match and your results have no `NULL` values in the key columns.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, what was inconsistent? I'll correct my question. And I tried your query but the `SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY` aspect doesn't seem to work – is this definitely MySQL syntax?

Comment: @Forest . . . There is no `type` in your query.  The `OVER` is a window function and has been supported in MySQL starting with MySQL 8.0.

Comment: Thank you, I've corrected that. The first block was intended to be the desired output rather than the current data format, but I can understand why that would make it hard to follow. I've also clarified in my question that this is for MySQL 5.7 – I am adding functionality to an older system.